# pairwise subtraction of arrays in python

Tags: python, numpy, knn

I have two matrices, A of shape 512*3 and B of shape 1024*3
I want to calculate pairwise subtraction between their rows, so the result would be of shape 512*1024*3

(they are actually arrays of 3D point coordinates : x , y , z and I eventually want to find k nearest points from B to every point in A)

and I can't use for loops. is there any pythonic way to do this?
thank u.

Comment: Can you tell us what you've tried so far in terms of code?

Comment: Post your code so far.  Among o ther things, this will show what structures you *really* have.  Python, per se, has no array or matrix structure.

Comment: Packages that support those structures have `product` or `join` methods to do the iteration you want.  Python has the `itertools.product` method.

Comment: You should look into [broadcasting](http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/EricsBroadcastingDoc)

Comment: `A[:, np.newaxis] - B[np.newaxis, :]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the reference I linked in my previous comment:

http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/EricsBroadcastingDoc

You are trying to do this.

[image]

Just follow the example, as in:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)

a = np.random.uniform(size=(8,3)) # or (512,3)
b = np.random.uniform(size=(16,3)) # or (1024,3)

diff = a[np.newaxis,:,:]-b[:,np.newaxis,:]

dist = np.sqrt(np.sum(diff**2,axis=-1))
```

Comment: This saved so much time for me to code things up. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The difference:

```
diff = A[:, np.newaxis] - B[np.newaxis, :]
```

The closest `k` points in `B` for each point in `A`:

```
k = 5
dists = np.sum(np.square(A[:, np.newaxis] - B[np.newaxis, :]), axis=-1)
top_k = np.argpartition(dists, k, axis=1)[:, :k]
```

That `top_k` is not sorted by distance, though. You can sort it later or do instead:

```
top_k = np.argsort(dists, axis=1)[:, :k]
```

Which is less efficient but simpler.